# Docker -> cant find mwnw

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

in regarding to this tutorial
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-mysql-react-docker-compose-example/

i get the message 
**bin/sh: ./mvnw not found** 
in my Dockerfile on this line

-> **RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B**

the dockerfile and mvnw are in the same directonary

[image][1]

i tried the following steps

-> replace the relative path with a absolute path
   **RUN C:users/..../mvnw dependency:go-offline -B**

-> reinstall mvnw with **./mvnw clean install -e**

but the two steps didnt help.

in comment #1 and #3 of the tutorial you can see that othe people has a similar problem. So how can i fix the problem ?

Comment: Everything is working here

Comment: Are you running the docker-compose ?